# Get the first digit of a Long when not sure how many digits will be in the long

Tags: long-integer, digits

I'm trying to get the first Digit of a Long but the Long i'm getting in from the user will be between 13 - 16 digits long how can I get that first Digit without knowing the exact length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just format it into a character buffer and get the first one. Only if that becomes a performance bottleneck, come back for a more complex solution.

In Java:

```
// assuming the number is non-negative, 
// otherwise need to deal with sign
String firstDigit = String.valueOf(myLong).substring(0,1);
```

Comment: hmm, yeah I tried turning it into a String then getting the first Char and converting that into an int but I get the ascii value of the char not its true value, fyi this is Java if that matters i'm still a beginner

Comment: @Jclark35 If you want to convert a character that is a digit into an int, you can just subtract `'0'`.  You can also use `Character.digit(firstChar,10)`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit-char-int-.

Comment: thanks yeah I actually just used to that find the sum of all even digits in a long public static int sumOfEvenDigits ( long number, int k)
{
int sum = 0, i =0;
char evenDigits;
String creditCardNumber = Long.toString(number);
while ( i < k)
{
evenDigits = creditCardNumber.charAt(i);
sum = sum + (Character.digit(evenDigits, 10));
i = i +2;
}
return sum;

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned this is Java.  In Java (and many C based languages), division of integers returns an integer and throws the remainder away.  This means that while you have a multiple digit number (in other words, greater than 9), you can divide by 10 to remove the last digit.  What you end up with is a single digit number that was the first digit of the original number:

```
if ( myLong < 0 ) {
    myLong *= -1;
}
while ( myLong > 9 ) {
    myLong /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Nice. This looks to be the fastest solution. Can also handle negative numbers by doing a `*= -1` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

The number of digits a number has is just `(int)log_10(n)`. Therefore a power of 10 with the same number of digits as n is `(int)pow(10, (int)log_10(n))`.

The last digit therefore is just `n / (int)pow(10, (int)log_10(n))`.

In Java this translates to:

```
long n = 8797123456789L;
long numDigs = (long)Math.log10(n);
long lastDigit = n / (long)Math.pow(10, numDigs);
System.out.println(lastDigit);

>> 8
```

Comment: hmm, yeah I tried turning it into a String then getting the first Char and converting that into an int but I get the ascii value of the char not its true value, fyi this is Java if that matters i'm still a beginner

Comment: You don't ever need to turn it into a string, my cast to ints were because the functions return double.

Comment: If you want Java you should add a Java tag to your question and then I'll post Java code to begin with.

Comment: I'd be worried that rounding errors could mess things up when `numDigs` is close to an integer.  Do you know if this would work reliably?

Comment: My worry was justified: `1e18-1` reports a first digit of `0`.

Comment: Yeah I saw. Blurgh. I guess I have to rewrite some of my code.

Comment: For me 1e14-1 returned having 14 digits instead of 13.